# extracting more than 20 variables by importance via varImp

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm dealing with a large dataset that involves more than 100 features (which are all relevant because they have already been filtered; the original dataset had over 500 features). I created a random forest model via the train() function from the caret package and using the "ranger" method.

Here's the question: how does one extract **all** of the variables by importance, as opposed to only the **top 20 most important** variables? The varImp() function yields only the top 20 variables by default.

Here's some sample code (minus the training set, which is very large):

```
library(caret)
rforest_model <- train(target_variable ~ .,
                       data = train_data_set,
                       method = "ranger",
                       importance = "impurity)
```

And here's the code for extracting variable importance:

```
varImp(rforest_model)
```

Comment: Note that importance() doesn't work in this case:

`importance(rforest_model)`

results in the following error message:

_Error in UseMethod("importance") : 
  no applicable method for 'importance' applied to an object of class "c('train', 'train.formula')"_

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The varImp function extracts importance for all variables (even if they are not used by the model), it just prints out the top 20 variables. Consider this example:

```
library(mlbench) #for data set
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(998)
data(Ionosphere)

rforest_model <- train(y = Ionosphere$Class,
                       x = Ionosphere[,1:34],
                       method = "ranger",
                       importance = "impurity")

nrow(varImp(rforest_model)$importance) #34 variables extracted
```

lets check them:

```
varImp(rforest_model)$importance %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  arrange(Overall) %>%
  mutate(rowname = forcats::fct_inorder(rowname )) %>%
  ggplot()+
    geom_col(aes(x = rowname, y = Overall))+
    coord_flip()+
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

note that V2 is a zero variance feature in this data set hence it has 0 importance and is not used by the model at all.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly

(I had tried pretty much every possible combination of varImp and importance *except* `varImp(rforest_model)$importance` haha)

Comment: @Flavio Abdenur Glad to help. If the answer solved your problem [consider marking as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Done, @missuse. I'm new on Stackoverflow, so still getting the hang on it :)